# Update the close reasons on Area 51

Tags: feature-request, area-51, close-reasons

Area 51 is still using the old close reasons. Could we update them to match the new and improved system?

Comment: I suspect that that is going to take a lot more effort; as I've understood things, Area 51 runs on a fork of an earlier version of the stack.

Comment: You mean Area 51 main? Meta has the new close reasons.

Comment: @AsheeshR Yes, of course.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I _suppose_ it can be just an aesthetic change. There's no need to bring per-proposal close reasons to the engine (although it'd be pretty awesome).